# Heroku Memory quota exceeded)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been receiving the error :

```
2019-05-18T17:17:44.785307+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=622M(121.6%)
2019-05-18T17:17:44.785432+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
```

The code on the view is:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "//static.opentok.com/webrtc/v2.2/js/TB.min.js" %>

<div id="videobox" style="position:relative; z-index:0; height: 500px"></div>
<hr style="margin-bottom: 5px; margin-top: 5px">

<script type="text/javascript">

    var apiKey = '<%= Figaro.env.opentok_api_key %>';
    var session_id = '<%= @stream.tokbox_session_id %>';
    var token = '<%= @tok_token %>';
    // (optional) add server code here
    initializeSession();

    // Handling all of our errors here by alerting them
    function handleError(error) {
        if (error) {
            alert(error.message);
        }
    }

    function initializeSession() {
        var session = OT.initSession(apiKey, session_id, 'videobox');
        // Create a publisher
        var publisher = OT.initPublisher('publisher', 'videobox', {
            insertMode: 'append',
            width: 'auto', height: 500,
            name: '<%= @stream.name %> ',
            mirror: false
        }, handleError);
        // Connect to the session
        session.connect(token, function (error) {
            // If the connection is successful, publish to the session
            if (error) {
                handleError(error);
            } else {
                session.publish(publisher, handleError);
            }
        });
    }

    function myFunction() {
        var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
        copyText.select();
        document.execCommand("copy");
        var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip");
        tooltip.innerHTML = "Copied: " + copyText.value;
    }

    function outFunc() {
        var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip");
        tooltip.innerHTML = "Copy to clipboard";
    }
</script>
```

My controler is very simple too:

```
 [![def stream
    @messages = Chatmessage.all
    @videomotion = Videomotion.new(videomotion_params)
      @opentok = OpenTok::OpenTok.new Figaro.env.opentok_api_key, Figaro.env.opentok_api_secret
      @stream = Stream.find_by(user_id: current_user.id)
      @tok_token = @opentok.generate_token(@stream.tokbox_session_id, :role => :publisher, :expire_time => 30.days.from_now)
  end][1]][1]
```

This is when trying to load some video items.

I tried everything that I could find so far :

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS -Xmx256m
RUBY_GC_HEAP_GROWTH_FACTOR1.03
WEB_CONCURRENCY 1
```

Are set up in my heroku config.

I also upgraded to Professional Dynos.
Does anybody knows what i am missing please? I followed the instructions on Heroku help page, with no luck.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "load up some video items"? Could you show us your code? It's possible you're simply loading some very large files into memory unnecessarily, no amount of Heroku tweaking will help that.

Comment: Apoogies for the poor phrasing, I am creating a Video Stream, using Tokbox. I followed this mini-tutorial : https://blog.sumatosoft.com/build-your-live-streaming-service-with-ruby-on-rails-and-tokbox/ . The video works well locally, online I get the R14 error.

Comment: I'm going to guess it's working locally because your local machine probably has a lot more memory than a Heroku Dyno. You likely have 4 to 16 GB. A Standard-1x dyno has just 512 MB. But without seeing your code I can't say what the problem is. If you can make available a version of your app with the secrets removed maybe someone can help.

Comment: @Schwern, I added the code, but there is not much I could figure out just by looking at it.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is this:

```
@messages = Chatmessage.all
```

Unless `Chatmessage` has a default scope, this is loading every row from the `chatmessages` table into memory.

Comment: hey, but that table is empty actually. I don t mind removing it, but there is no data.